# Discrete Fourier Transform sample frequencies using numpy

Tags: python, time-series, fft

I'm using numpy to calculate sample frequencies, specifically **fft.fftfreq(n, d=1.0)**.

I want to calculate **d**. Is there any formula or a library I can use to calculate **d**?

How can I calculate the sampling rate of a time-series dataset, because **d** is the inverse of the sampling rate?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the total time of that time series (in seconds) and the number of points? Your sample rate should be the number of points per second in your series.

Comment: Looks like you need something like [`infer_freq()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.infer_freq.html), which is part of the `pandas` libary.

Comment: The time-series dataset is daily, which means the index is like this yyyy-mm-dd. The frequency that I got is 1/len(dataset). and d is the scalar that changes the frequency. I want a formula to calculate it correctly. I don't want to use guessing

Comment: @mosc9575, infer_freq returns 'D' if the data is daily, which I already know it's daily and the frequency is D

Answer (score 0):

You must read a little about sampling rate before looking to a "magic function".

According to [numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html) the parameter 'd' is "Sample spacing (inverse of the sampling rate)."

Looking for [Sampling rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing)), the 'd' is equivalent to 'T' in time which stands for Period (the time in seconds between each sample). But you're using the DFT, so you can choose the time unit. If you have 1 sample per day, you 'd' is 1 and the result of fftfreq will be in cycles/day. If you have 2 samples per day, your 'd' is 1/2 to have the output in cycles/day.

So, the function you're looking for is just  1/(samples per time unit), where the time unit could be days, hours, minutes, seconds ...

If you have the timestamps of your samples, you can calculate de 'd' as the time difference between each one. There is no way to calculate that without knowing some information about the signal.